# Grab a users URL with $Location and place in SQL database?

Tags: javascript, c#, sql, angularjs

So I have an end-user and they are submitting a form on a global div with a button that opens a popup.

Long story short, they fill this form out and submit the HTTP methods with Angular RESTing methods.

I'm trying to figure out how I can grab that users current URL from where they access the popup, or submit it from.

I want to put that URL in a SQL database to understand where users are finding bugs or where they are clicking this button from (The purpose of the popup is to gain information and recieve feedback)

What's the right way of going about this?

```
$windows.location? 
$Location? 
$routeparams?
```

I really need some help. i'll post my client-side angular below, the back-end that takes these requests and puts it in the SQL databases are done by my C# Controller.

```
(function() {
'use strict';

var commonModule = angular.module('ambassadors.commonModule');

commonModule.service('commonService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {

    this.getSettingsView = function() {

        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.get('/api/settings')
            .success(function(response) {
                deferred.resolve(response);
            })
            .error(function() {
                deferred.reject();
            });

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    this.getUserClaims = function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.get('/api/profile')
            .success(function(response) {
                deferred.resolve(response);
            })
            .error(function(response) {
                deferred.reject(response);
            });

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    this.submitFeedback = function(feedback, file) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        if (file != null) {
            var that = this;
            this.uploadFile(file).then(
                // Success Handler 
                function(result) {
                    // update the scec icon in the controller 
                    feedback.FeedbackUpload = result[0].location;
                    that.postFeedback(feedback, deferred);
                },
                // Failure Handler 
                function() {
                    $scope.messageInfo = "Error uploading feedback file";
                    return deferred.reject;
                });
        } else
            this.postFeedback(feedback, deferred);

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    this.postFeedback = function(feedback, deferred) {

        $http.post('/api/feedback', feedback)
            .success(function() {
                deferred.resolve();
            })
            .error(function() {
                deferred.reject();
            });
    }


    this.uploadFile = function(file) {

        // As per stackoverflow.com/questions/… 
        // uncorkedstudios.com/blog/… 

        var feedbackFileFormData = new FormData();
        feedbackFileFormData.append("file", file);

        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.post('/api/feedbackfile', feedbackFileFormData, {
                withCredentials: true,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': undefined
                },
                transformRequest: angular.identity
            })
            .success(function(response) {
                deferred.resolve(response);
            })
            .error(function() {
                deferred.reject();
            });

        return deferred.promise;
    };
 }]);
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Inject [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) service in your controller and then use

> The $location service parses the URL in the browser address bar (based
>   on the window.location) and makes the URL available to your
>   application. Changes to the URL in the address bar are reflected into
>   $location service and changes to $location are reflected into the
>   browser address bar.

```
var absUrl = $location.absUrl();
// => "http://example.com/#/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo"
```

Comment: Just to gain some clarity, where exactly in my angular? My commonModule.service('commonService', [ Right?

Comment: Yes where you want, you can inject it. Simply in `service` or `factory` or `controller`. Happy Angular :-)

Comment: Like `commonModule.service('commonService', ['$http', '$q', '$location', function($http, $q, $location) {`

Comment: Thank you so much for the help Vineet, so I added the $location information to my commonModule. How will I be able to place this information in my database?

Comment: Pass `absUrl` variable value in your `AJAX` call AKA `$http.post()` and then save your value in your DB.

Comment: @Royalgambino Why Downvote ? If you have any query, please ask .